# script parsing results to the same email

Tags: windows, powershell

I am outputting the results of a powershell script to a html file which is emailed to me via exchange, I need to get the script to stop parsing the results to the same email and create a new email on each run. I have tried a different subject line but it will still parse to the same email address.

```
$Subject = "Win7 Printer Report from script"

$ToAddress = "email@adddress.com"

$FromAddress = "email@adddress.com"

send-mailmessage -to $ToAddress -from $FromAddress -subject $Subject -smtpserver vmserver.server.com -body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

This is the full script.

```
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory



$comps = "12345"







foreach ($comp in $comps)

{

                $count++

                $printers = get-printer -computername $comp

                foreach ($printer in $printers)

                {

                                $p_name = $printer.name

                                $p_shared = $printer.shared

                                $p_published = $printer.published

                                $p_sharename = $printer.sharename

                                $p_drivername = $printer.drivername



                                $drivStr = $null



                                $drivers = get-printerdriver $p_drivername -computername $comp

                                foreach ($driver in $drivers)

                                {

                                                $d_environment = $driver.PrinterEnvironment


                                                $drivStr += "$d_environment | "

                                }             

                                $t_file_content += "<tr class=greyback><td>$comp</td><td>$p_name</td><td>$p_shared</td><td>$p_published</td><td>$p_sharename</td><td>$p_drivername</td><td>$drivStr</td></tr>"

                }

}

$t_file_header = "<div class=ibmtitle>Win7 Printer Report</div><table><tr class=blueback><td>Computer</td><td>Name</td><td>Shared</td><td>Published</td><td>Share Name</td><td>Driver Name</td><td>Driver Type</td></tr>"

$t_file_footer = "</table><br>"

$t_file = $t_file_header + $t_file_content + $t_file_footer

$endDTM = (Get-Date)

$ts = ($endDTM-$startDTM)

$ts_display = '{0:00}h {1:00}m {2:00}s' -f $ts.Hours,$ts.Minutes,$ts.Seconds

$ScriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path

$host_name = $env:COMPUTERNAME

$infobox = "<br><table style='width:100%'><tr class=greyback><td><b>Script:</b> $ScriptPath<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<b>Server:</b> $host_name<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<b>Script run time:</b> $ts_display<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<b>Description:</b> Checks printers on selected servers.<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<b>Computers:</b> $count<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "<br>"

$infobox = $infobox + "</td></tr></table>"

$html_header = "<html><head>" + $a + "</head><body>"

$body_main = $body_main + $t_file + $infobox

$html_footer = "</body></html>"

$body = $html_header + $body_main + $html_footer

$Subject = "Win7 Printer Report"

$ToAddress = "me@lol.com"

$FromAddress = "me@rofl.com""

send-mailmessage -to $ToAddress -from $FromAddress -subject $Subject -smtpserver vm.lol.com -body $body -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: You want to change the from address for each email sent? It's a bit unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: When I run the script, it keeps adding the results to the original message, so the message is growing each time I run it, its a small XML email at the moment, but I would like the script to create a new email instead.

Comment: Do you have any global variables not being set to $null at the end of the script?

Comment: Without seeing more of the script loop structure... can only suggest that you need to reset $body to $null when you assign the new $toAddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you're mailing a "file" and you have variables with the name "file" in the code you posted. Yet there is no file related activity in that code. You've also got $comps as a string, when it needs to be an array. It feels like this code has been modified before posting. There is a time to post abbreviated code, but when you do so, you need to do it carefully.

If you are really mailing a file, and appending to the same file each day, that could result in the problem you describe. Make sure you erase that file each day if that's the case, or write a new file each day by naming it with YearMonthDay or something.

If I am mistaken and there really is no file try adding `$t_file_content = $null` at the top of your script.

**Edit 1**
Try adding `$body_main = $null` at the top of your script.

Comment: There's been no modification to the code, it is what it is, I'm new to PS, I have added your suggestion $t_file_content = $null and it makes no difference. For clarity, the XML file is embedded into the email, not as a file attachment, so that might explain the confusion,  the email is now 2mb in size. So I need to figure out how to stop it growing.